# Custom filter updates ignore tag combinations

Tags: bug, filtering, custom-filter

I have custom filters that combine tags like this

[python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class)

When I load the page, I see the results I expect: questions that are tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) AND [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class)

However, when the page fetches "questions with new activity", the fetched questions may be tagged with only [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class) - the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) may not be present.  In fact, it seems that the first tag is ignored, so the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)[class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class) combination receives updates for [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class), whereas the [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class)[python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) combination receives updates for [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

If I reload the page, only questions with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) AND [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class) are displayed, as expected.

I first started to notice this behaviour a couple of weeks ago: previously the page load and "new questions" behaved consistently.

Browser is Firefox 68.4.2esr, on Linux.

Comment: @yivi, I can't say that the dupe target _answers_ my question, as it's not answered :-/  But nevertheless, it's the same issue, thanks for finding it.

Comment: The dupe comment content is auto-generated.